# Use LINQ to create .mdf file

Tags: sql, linq

I'm trying to create a .mdf database using linq. Here's the code.

```
 public class Repository : DataContext
    {
        public Repository(string connection) : base(connection)
        {
            if (!this.DatabaseExists())
                this.CreateDatabase();
        }
    }
```

And I invoked it like this:

```
Repository rp = new Repository(@"E:\sample.mdf");
```

But it always throws instance not found error. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: `.mdf` is a SQL Server datafile - you don't typically just "create" those from code - you need to create those on the server and not as stand-alone files (those aren't Access or SQLite files - those are server-based databases)...

Comment: so what should I do? I want to deploy it to a PC where no SQL installed.

Comment: If you want to use a `.mdf` file, there **must be** at last SQL Server **Express** installed ....

Comment: @marc_s thanks. I know that. Could you give me an idea for creating an app with its own db?

Comment: When you have SQL Server installed, use SQL scripts to create the database and the database objects - not Linq.

Comment: thanks @marc_s. I can't force the client to install SQL Server. I think I should check some other options.